# How to track, if the file has changed in the UWP App?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Is there any way to track, if the file I picked using the **fileopenpicker** changed? I have an **UWP APP**, which takes data from excel and does sth. with it, but every time I want to take data from the excel file, I have to use file picker again, which makes it useless. Do you know how to automate such task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FutureAccessList` or `MostRecnetUsedList` to access the file without using the file picker every time.

```
    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Add to MRU with metadata (For example, a string that represents the date)
    string mruToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file, "20120716");

    // Add to FA without metadata
    string faToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);  
}
else
{
    // The file picker was dismissed with no file selected to save
}
```

For more info, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist?view=winrt-19041#examples).